how to install Bunch using PIP
C:\Coding1\Coding>pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org bunchDefaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeableCollecting bunchUsing cached bunch-1.0.1.zip (11 kB)Installing build dependencies ... doneGetting requirements to build wheel ... errorerror: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.│ exit code: 1╰─> [20 lines of output]Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>main()File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in mainjson_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheelreturn hook(config_settings)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dd90kil7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheelreturn self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dd90kil7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 304, in _get_build_requiresself.run_setup()File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dd90kil7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 522, in run_setupsuper().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dd90kil7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setupexec(code, locals())File "<string>", line 11, in <module>ValueError: invalid mode: 'rU'[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.│ exit code: 1╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I tried pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org bunch
and pip install bunch
but none of it worked, only showing that error.

bunch 1.0.1 was released in 2011. Supported Python versions (see the bottom of the left column, section "Programming Language"): Python 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7.
The package is outdated and abandoned. You cannot install it with modern Python.
Upd. See How to use a dot "." to access members of dictionary? ; there is a bunch (pun intended) of answers with code you can copy and use; some answers mentioned DotMap, Box, dotwiz. Munch seems to be a forked and updated version of Bunch.
